# Is there a tool to comment out a function quickly?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm doing a major refactoring on my project, and frankly my fingers are getting tired.  I want to be able to comment out a function/sub quickly so that would change this:

```
    Public Function FooBar()
        dim x as integer
        dim y as integer
        dim z as integer
    End Function
```

to this:

```
    Public Function FooBar()
        throw new exception("refactoring required")
        'dim x as integer
        'dim y as integer
        'dim z as integer
    End Function
```

Is there some sort of tool that will allow me to click the function name then make the changes?

Comment: You can write a command in Visual Commander to automate this task using DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection and ActivePoint.CodeElement http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one for a function/method specifically, but there is one for the highlighted selection.

- Select the lines to comment
- Press `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C` to comment those lines
- Press `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U` to uncomment those lines